# How to cache all requests in browser?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

My Webapp is React -> .NET -> SQL

I want to cache all post requests such that all .NET calls are made just once,  next time it's fed from cache. For every small UI change in react I want to use the cache and save development time.

As it's Just for development, looking or something in Chrome maybe, is there an extension for such a task or any guide to what I should look into will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`chrome.storag.local`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) API where you can store, retrieve, and track changes to user data.

You can use it like this based from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766467/how-do-i-cache-data-in-chrome-extension):

```
function fetchLive(callback) {
  doSomething(function(data) {
    chrome.storage.local.set({cache: data, cacheTime: Date.now()}, function() {
      callback(data);
    });
  });
}

function fetch(callback) {
  chrome.storage.local.get(['cache', 'cacheTime'], function(items) {
    if (items.cache && items.cacheTime && items.cacheTime) {
      if (items.cacheTime > Date.now() - 3600*1000) {
        return callback(items.cache); // Serialization is auto, so nested objects are no problem
      }
    }

    fetchLive(callback);
  });
}
```

Just remember that:

> [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) employs two caches — an **on-disk cache** and a **very fast in-memory cache**. The lifetime of an in-memory cache is attached to the
>   lifetime of a render process, which roughly corresponds to a tab.
>   Requests that are answered from the in-memory cache are invisible to
>   the web request API.